# Probability of reaching node A from node B in exactly X steps

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a three-node matrix with two edges (A-B and A-C). I would like to determine what the probability is starting from B and ending at C in exactly 100 steps.

I have only written out probabilities:

```
P(A|B) = 1
P(B|A) = 0.5
P(A|C) = 1
P(C|A) = 0.5
```

But there are so many combinations of ways to get from B to C in exactly 100 steps using these probabilities. Any suggestions on how to continue this problem?

Comment: Thanks you! I get a transition matrix of ([0,.5,.5],[1,0,0],[1,0,0]) where the first block [] is the top row. The rows and columns are labeled A, B, C. When I multiply the initial vector times (transition matrix)^100, I get [0, 0,5, 0.5], which means it has 1/2 chance of being at B and half chance of being at C. This makes sense because it will be at either B or C after an even number of moves, and A after an odd number of moves.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I somehow "edited" your comment, when I meant to just "comment"!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an odd number of steps you must be at A and after an even number of steps you will be in either B or C, each with probability 0.5, therefore after 100 steps the probability of being in C is 0.5

**Edit**

More formally we can define a Markov chain with transition matrix:

$$ T = \left(\array{0&\tfrac{1}{2}&\tfrac{1}{2}\\1&0&0\\1&0&0}\right) $$

Now we can compute $T^2$ and $T^3$ to show that for $n\ge 1$, $T^{2n-1}=T$:

$$ T^2 = \left(\array{1&0&0\\0&\tfrac{1}{2}&\tfrac{1}{2}\\0&\tfrac{1}{2}&\tfrac{1}{2}}\right) $$

$$ T^3 = \left(\array{0&\tfrac{1}{2}&\tfrac{1}{2}\\1&0&0\\1&0&0}\right) = T $$

Therefore we calculate that $T^{100}=T^2$ and that $x_0 T^{100} = x_0 T^2$

$$ x_0 T^2 = \left(\array{0&1&0}\right) \left(\array{1&0&0\\0&\tfrac{1}{2}&\tfrac{1}{2}\\0&\tfrac{1}{2}&\tfrac{1}{2}}\right) = \left(\array{0&\tfrac{1}{2}&\tfrac{1}{2}}\right) $$